# Mysql Returning some user selected value with empty table

Tags: mysql, sql, return-value

I'm trying to select any value from the select query like this :

```
            select  1 as status_value
            from    tab1
```

The table "tab1" containing no data. I want to display the following output

```
            status_value
            ____________
                 1
```

is it possible ?

Comment: What should it show if there is data in `tab1`?

Comment: if there is data in the table then it should show selected columns from tab1 along with status_value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dummy table "DUAL" like:

```
SELECT 1 AS status_value FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Hi, Please correct this query :   

SELECT  1 AS status_value 
FROM  DUAL d
LEFT    JOIN svk_apt_votings v on true

Here, I want to jaoin some other tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL`. First do your `SELECT` from `tab1`. Then `UNION ALL` a `SELECT` from `dual` with nulls for the columns that correspond to the columns of the first `SELECT` and the literal status. To make sure this extra row isn't added when `tab1` contains rows add a `WHERE` clause, that checks that no data can be found in `tab1`.

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       ...
       coln,
       1 status_value
       FROM tab1
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,
       NULL,
       ...
       NULL,
       1
       FROM dual
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM tab1);
```

Comment: this union is adding null row for the result. But I want status_value to be displayed as a column of first select without UNION ALL .

Comment: @KiranKumar: If you just always want one row with exactly one column named `status_value` and a value of `1`, you could simply do `SELECT 1 status_value` without a `FROM`. If this is also not what you want you have to edit your question and describe what you want in detail, with samples.